# Prevent inserting matching rows in MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in MySql Database. I would like to prevent inserting matching rows in MySql. Like I have 4 columns in a table. I would not like to insert any row which has matching values of these 4 columns. I am trying to show that below

```
My table
----------
 product_name| product_sku |product_quantity| product_price
----------
 Computer    | comp_007    | 5              | 500
```

I would like to prevent to insert same row again. How can I do that using MySql Query ??

**UPDATE**

I would not like to insert again

---

```
 Computer    | comp_007    | 5              | 500
```

But I would like to insert below rows

---

```
 mouse       | comp_007    | 5               | 500
```

---

```
 Computer    | comp_008    | 5               | 500
```

---

```
 Computer    | comp_007    | 50              | 500
```

---

```
 Computer    | comp_007    | 5               | 100
```

---

```
 mouse       | mou_007     | 5               | 500
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a combined unique key / composite key on the columns in question:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE (
`product_name` ,
`product_sku` ,
`product_quantity`,
`product_price`
);
```

Any attempts to insert duplicate rows will result in a MySQL error.

Answer (score 1):

If possible you should add a **Unique Key** to your columns:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `ix_name` (`product_name`, `product_sku`, `product_quantity`, `product_price`);
```

and then use `INSERT IGNORE`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_name (product_name, product_sku, product_quantity, product_price) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, value4);
```

If the record is unique `MYSQL` inserts it as usual, if the record is a duplicate then the `IGNORE` keyword discards the insert without generating an error.

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ba23/1)

Comment: did you get my question ??

Comment: @abuabu did you try my solution? 
This will work, you can also check the SQLFiddle link I have posted in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to make your columns unique. On undesired inserts, your MySQL driver should throw an exception then, which you can handle.

From a domain logic point of view, this is a bad practice, since exceptions should never handle expected behaviour. By the way, your DB table could use a primary key.

So, to have a better solution, your approach could be:
- Define a unique field (the SKU seems suitable); think about using this as the primary key as well
- With MySQL, use a REPLACE statement:

```
REPLACE INTO your_tablename
SET product_name='the name'
-- and so on for other columns
WHERE product_sku = 'whatever_sku';
```

REPLACE does the Job of trying to INSERT, and doing an UPDATE instead if the PK exists.